# how to fetch name in instead of id in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, export-to-csv

I have a ServiceProvider model. When I import it in CSV it provider ID of category, country, state, city, name. How I fetch the name instead of ID while import in CSV.

***Here is my models.py***

```
class ServiceProvider(models.Model):
    name = models.OneToOneField('accounts.User', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    Date_Of_Birth = models.DateField(null=True)
    # upload_Photograph = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/') 
    Education_Qualification  = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Category', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='category')
    phone_No = models.IntegerField(null=False)
    alternate_No = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    bank_account_no = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    IFSC_code = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    branch_name = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    PAN = models.CharField(max_length=254, null=True)
    country = models.ForeignKey('accounts.Country', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='country')
    state = models.ForeignKey('accounts.State', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='state')
    cities = models.ForeignKey('accounts.City', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='cities')
    address = models.CharField(max_length=254)


    def __str__(self):
        return self.name.username
```

***Here is my views.py***

```
@login_required
def export_csv(request):
    response = HttpResponse(content_type='text/csv')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="user-serviceprovider.xls"'
    writer = csv.writer(response)
    writer.writerow(['name', 'Date_Of_Birth', 'Education_Qualification', 'category','phone_No','alternate_No','bank_account_no','IFSC_code','branch_name','PAN','country','state','cities','address'])
    users = ServiceProvider.objects.all().values_list('name', 'Date_Of_Birth', 'Education_Qualification', 'category','phone_No','alternate_No','bank_account_no','IFSC_code','branch_name','PAN','country','state','cities','address')
    for user in users:
      writer.writerow(user)     
    return response
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you really is need is a little tweak like this:

```
...
users = ServiceProvider.objects.all().values_list('name__username', 'Date_Of_Birth', 'Education_Qualification', 'category','phone_No','alternate_No','bank_account_no','IFSC_code','branch_name','PAN','country','state','cities','address')
...
```

Notice that `'name__username'`, it tells Django to go a bit deeper and select the `username` column from the `accounts.User` table because plain `'name'` refers to the foreign key in the `ServiceProvider` table (here `username` is just an example, the actual name of the column really depends on the schema of your `accounts.User` table).

Comment: Thanks for answer . It fulfill my requirement

Answer (score 0):

```
for u in users:
   row = [u.id, u.name, u.yourfield, ...]
   writer.writerow(row)
```